# How to use imageSearch with transparent image?

Tags: image-processing, png, autohotkey, transparent

I'm trying to find a transparent image on the screen. But it can't find the picture because its edges are transparent. Is there any solution method? it may like a library or win api. Maybe my use is wrong.

Used image file:[image: http://pngimg.com/uploads/light/light_PNG14440.png]

```
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0,0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight,*50 *TransBlack C:\Users\PC\Desktop\light_PNG14440.png
if (ErrorLevel = 2)
     MsgBox Could not conduct the search.
else if (ErrorLevel = 1)
MsgBox Icon could not be found on the screen.
else
MsgBox The icon was found at %FoundX%x%FoundY%.
```

I expect the output to be `The icon was found at 100x100.`, but the actual output is `Icon could not be found on the screen.`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the entire image, search for a part of the image that does not have transparency.
In this case the central part of the image seems like a good candidate for this.
After you get the position of the central part, getting the position of the entire image is just a simple calculation.

Comment: I thought about you said. if there is transparency in the center how can i do? eg a circle

Comment: I guess you will have to find a different part of the image that does not have transparency and use that.

Comment: how can i find non-transparent area of a circle?If I pick a part of the picture, I can't prove it's a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using ImageSearch you could use [FindText](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17834)